# How to I create a Document Object based on user HTML input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a textarea meant to a take in user HTML input, and my purpose is to take out all the inline styling and the style tags from that HTML.

I initially thought about just changing the whole thing to a string and doing what I needed to, but then I realized I could use the DOM.

Is there anyway I can create a DOM object from the HTML in a textarea put in by the user?

This way I can traverse the inputted DOM and remove the inline styles & style tags, add classes/ids to those elements, and apply those styles in some generated css.

Could I get some help on this first part of creating a DOM from HTML in a text area? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a jQuery object from the HTML.

```
var stringHTML = $('.html-textarea').val(); //string of textarea contents

$html = $(stringHTML);
```

Then you can do whatever jQuery operations (traversal, etc.) that you need to.

Comment: Wow, Thanks! So now this new DOM is the $html object? Is there something similar if the user input CSS in the textarea, so I can make a $css object?

Is there also a way to convert it back to HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the built-in innerHTML function.  No libraries are required.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the CSS style attributes in a container like this:

```
<style id="myStyles">

  div.headerStyle  {
    font-family: helvetica;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 2.5em;  
    margin-top: 1.5em
  }

  h1.titleFont {
    color: #000080;
    width: 500px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    text-align: center;
  }

</style>
```

Then you could include these style elements in a custom DOM element like this:

```
<script>
  function updateTextArea( content ) {
     var html = '<textarea class="myStyle">';
     html += content;
     html += '</textarea>';
     document.getElementById("myTextArea").innerHTML = html;
  }
</script>
```